# How to render react-data-grid in non index file with exporting?

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I am using react-data-grid for rendering data but it's only working in the `index.js` file but when I am using in normal file I am not able to export the file by defining class & also with the function name.

Tried exporting with class name & function name.

```
import React, { useState, Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";
import { Toolbar, Data } from "react-data-grid-addons";
import createRowData from "./createRowData";

const defaultColumnProperties = {
  filterable: true,
  width: 200
};

const selectors = Data.Selectors;

const columns = [
  {
    key: "ID",
    name: "ID"
  },
  {
    key: "Data",
    name: "Data"
  },
  {
    key: "firstname",
    name: "first name"
  },
  {
    key: "amount",
    name: "Amount"
  }
].map(c => ({ ...c, ...defaultColumnProperties }));

const ROW_COUNT = 50;

const handleFilterChange = filter => filters => {
  const newFilters = { ...filters };
  if (filter.filterTerm) {
    newFilters[filter.column.key] = filter;
  } else {
    delete newFilters[filter.column.key];
  }
  return newFilters;
};

function getRows(rows, filters) {
  return selectors.getRows({ rows, filters });
}

function Example({ rows }) {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
  const filteredRows = getRows(rows, filters);
  return (
    <ReactDataGrid
      columns={columns}
      rowGetter={i => filteredRows[i]}
      rowsCount={filteredRows.length}
      minHeight={300}
      minWidth={1300}
      toolbar={<Toolbar enableFilter={true} />}
      onAddFilter={filter => setFilters(handleFilterChange(filter))}
      onClearFilters={() => setFilters({})}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Example rows={createRowData(50)} />, rootElement);
```

Need to export the file for routing, need to get data from another file for publishing in a Grid view along with filter functionality for searching fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the issue you are facing. Can you change the above to this

```
 const ROW_COUNT = 50;


const handleFilterChange = filter => filters => {
    const newFilters = { ...filters };
    if (filter.filterTerm) {
      newFilters[filter.column.key] = filter;
    } else {
      delete newFilters[filter.column.key];
    }
    return newFilters;
  };

  function getRows(rows, filters) {
    return selectors.getRows({ rows, filters });
  }

function Example({rows}) {
    //const rows = createRowData(50);
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
    const filteredRows = getRows(rows, filters);
    return (
      <ReactDataGrid
        columns={columns}
        rowGetter={i => filteredRows[i]}
        rowsCount={filteredRows.length}
        minHeight={500}
        toolbar={<Toolbar enableFilter={true} />}
        onAddFilter={filter => setFilters(handleFilterChange(filter))}
        onClearFilters={() => setFilters({})}
      />
    );
  }
class datagrid extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
        <Example rows={createRowData(50)} />);
    }
}

export default datagrid;
```

Comment: _Yes_.. **Thanks** it's **worked** I **achieved** the **Results**